# My footer will not stick to the bottom

Tags: html, css

So I am making a website like a little mock up one as I have just started learning and the footer just won't stay at the bottom and it is killing me. When I load the page it starts at the bottom and then when I scroll down it stays in the same place and is stuck where it started and won't start at the bottom of the page.

```
#footer {
    text-align: right;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #07889B;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 1200px;
```

}

Comment: There is many ways to achieve that eg. You set for everything else beneath footer min-height: 100vh and footer will always be at the bottom

Comment: It just won't start at the bottom of the page :(

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
#footer {
    text-align: right;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #07889B;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left:0;
    width: 1200px;//or width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Nope that just made it go to the left

Comment: This would work, you must be giving it a float on top or inside.  Check the fiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/fh49mank/